# Pod IP not accessible from master node

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, flannel

I have a 3 node kubernetes cluster, a master and two nodes on AWS that I created with kubeadm (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

I have created some deployments from the master node and I can see that pods are created on the 2 nodes for each of the deployments.
But the issue is I can't access the pod ip from the master or from the other node. So the pod ip is only accessible on the node where is pod is running.

I have a service of nodeport type, so when the service(pod1:port) hits the other pod(pod2), it hangs and times out

Thanks.

Comment: Almost identical today's question with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284335/kubernetes-cant-reach-other-node-services

Comment: @Alexey looks be be similar to the issue I have except I am on AWS. Were you using kubeadm,

Comment: @Alexey logs also look similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works either by disabling the firewall or by running below command.

I found this bug in my search. Looks like this is related to docker >=1.13 and flannel

refer: https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/799